# ValueChanged signal for PyQt

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am using Python with PyQt5 for programming user interface.

Now I have a variable inside the UI class in Python(type: ctypes.c_long), and it is changed by calling a function inside a .dll file with ctypes. Python passes this variable with C++ by address.

```
MyVariable = ctypes.c_long(0)
MyUI.MyDll.MyFunc(ctypes.byref(MyUI.MyVariable))
```

And in C++ (.dll file), the codes could be like:

```
int MyFunc(int& my_var){
    my_var = 5;
    return 1;
}
```

Since I cannot emit signal inside the C++ code (.dll file), I wish to have an elegent way to detect the value changing of with variable to sync with a progress bar.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of setting a timer to check the value and update the progress bar, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I called "the not elegant way". The reason for this is that I need to update a progressBar according to the change of this value. But the value for progressBar cannot be set in another thread, or it could crash down.

Comment: Why would you need another thread for a timer such as [`QTimer`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html)? It's integrated into the event loop of the current thread.

Comment: The ctypes function is for control of the hardware, and the other thread with time package is for updating the progressbar, w/o which the main GUI will be frozen while the functions are running.